# Error Phing - The Git tasks depend on PEAR's VersionControl_Git package

Tags: git, pear, phing

So I checked the following and I read the PEAR manual but still I'm having this error. [Phing error when using gitclone - Git tasks depend on PEAR\'s VersionControl_Git package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722511/phing-error-when-using-gitclone-git-tasks-depend-on-pear-s-versioncontrol-git)

The php.ini I use is `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/conf/php.ini`

I modified the include_path to the following:

```
include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/lib/php:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin/pear"
```

`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/lib/php` was already in the includes path so I added the pear path. I also used `/usr/local/bin/pear` but still no luck ... so I have no idea what path I actually have to put in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ pear list-files versioncontrol_git
Installed Files For versioncontrol_git
======================================
Type Install Path
php  /usr/share/php/VersionControl/Git/Object/Blob.php
php  /usr/share/php/VersionControl/Git/Object/Commit.php
```

Use the path of `php` files before `VersionControl` - in my case, the include path is `/usr/share/php/`.

Comment: I didn't find a solution for that specific problem. but I gave up and just made a regular shell script. it wasn't part of a big project so no problem there.